# java error: Could not find or load main class ass1.insert

Tags: java, javac

I have three java files `dictionary.java` `postings.java` and `invert.java`

The first line for all three is:

```
package project1;
```

The folder path for these are `Desktop/cps/`.

I have compiled the files using (while in the directory cps):

```
javac -d . *.java
```

... which creates a folder `project1` with all three `.class` files.

when I try to run using the following command:

```
java project.invert
```

I get that error:

> Could not find or load main class `project.insert`

How do i run `invert.java`?

The `invert.java` has the main class while the other two are just class definition files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There maybe a typo in your execution command. It should be `java project1.invert` notice the 1 with project. Further the signature of main method must have `String[] args` argument.
It should be

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

If the **access specifier** is missing then it will result in compile time error.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Folder path for all 3 files must be `Desktop/cps/project1` instead of `Desktop/cps/`.

Packages in Java represent directories in the file system.

You must compile while being in `Desktop/cps/` as `javac project1/*.java`

and run the program using `java project1.invert`

Comment: yes i have done that. and i still get the same error . im compiling and running from the cps directory

Comment: are you running it as `java project1.invert`? what error you get?

Comment: the error im getting is `Could not find or load main class project1.insert`

Comment: is it `invert` or `insert`?

Comment: sorry i meant to `invert` there isnt a `insert`

Comment: Are you running it as `project1.invert` or `project.invert`?